# C# Nunit - run two tests in parallel when passing in source data with yield returns

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, nunit

I would like to run the first and second tests one after the other for every set of data being returned as I'm setting the reportFilePath to a variable each time. I could make it just one test but I think thats too big

```
private string reportFilePath;

[Test]
[TestCaseSource(typeof(TestData.SwiftReporting), "GenerateDailyLargeExposureReport")]
[Order(4)]
public async Task ShouldGenerateDailyLargeExposureReport(int year, int month, int day)
    {
        ReportResponseModel dailyLargeExposureReport = new ReportResponseModel();

        DateTime date = new DateTime(year, month, day).Date;
        string formattedDate = date.ToString("d");

        dailyLargeExposureReport = await ReportLogic.RequestReport(date, (int)ReportsEnum.DailyLargeExposureReport, null, AuthToken);
        dailyLargeExposureReport.Should().NotBeNull();
        reportFilePath = dailyLargeExposureReport.FilePath;
    }


[Test]
[TestCaseSource(typeof(TestData.SwiftReporting), "DownloadDailyLargeExposureReport")]
[Order(8)]
public async Task ShouldDownloadDailyLargeExposureReport(int accountCount)
    {
        DailyLargeExposureReportModel outputReport = new DailyLargeExposureReportModel();
        outputReport = (DailyLargeExposureReportModel)await ReportLogic.DownloadReport(reportFilePath, ReportsEnum.DailyLargeExposureReport, AuthToken);

        List<DailyLargeExposureAccountModel> reportAccounts = outputReport.Accounts;
        reportAccounts.Count().Should().Be(7);
    }
```

Here is my data:

```
public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> GenerateDailyLargeExposureReport
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new TestCaseData(2017, 1, 2)
                .SetName("Generate DLE report for Account1, Jan 2");
            yield return new TestCaseData(2017, 1, 3)
                .SetName("Generate DLE report for Account1, Jan 3");
        }
    }

public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> DownloadDailyLargeExposureReport
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new TestCaseData(3)
                .SetName("Get data for Account1, Jan 2");
            yield return new TestCaseData(5)
                .SetName("Get data for Account1, Jan 3");
        }
    }
```

So I want to run both tests for the first set of data in each IEnumerable, then do it again with the second set.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it's not possible to do that unless you add `[Parallelizable]` to both methods. But that would allow all four tests to run in parallel, which is not what you want.

One way to restructure this would be to create a parameterized fixture containing two tests, using `TestFixtureSourceAttribute`. You could make the fixture instances non-parallelizable so that they didn't run together but the individual tests parallelizable so that they would.